# 8 or more buttons mouse for OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, mouse

I had a trust 6 button mouse (trust 15902) but when I updated to OS X Lion, it became almost useless, I could only use 3 button. I checked steer mouse, but it did not help much. So now I would like to ask a 6, 7, 8 or even more buttons mouse compatible with OS X Lion, could you recommend any?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall trust buttons software  with every OSX kernel update.
Alternatively 3Dconnexion or logitech button managers can do the trick.

Comment: for the trust 15902, there was no update for lion

Comment: You have options:
* USB overdrive - driver for all PC input devices
* 3Dconnexion - mouse driver to handle 20 buttons and 6 motion axes
* Logitech - historic option, long ago let assign any buttons to many functions, like enabling 4th button etc.

Comment: usb overdrive has no lion support and 3d connection, i will have a look

Comment: 3dxmacware 1.7 says it supports lion and monkey and wahtever.

Comment: i can not find the link to download the 3dxmacware

Comment: Go to http://www.3dconnexion.com/service/drivers.html
Choose cheapest product(spacewhatever for notebook) , downolad OSX software.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work, does not recognize my mouse of I can not use any of those strange buttons